# Is there a way to implement google sign in with and custom login with jwt token using spring security?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

As I am  new the springboot, I got stuck with a senario, pls help me out.
I have custom login page where it takes a username and password and validate it. If user
present, in my database then jwt token is generated, I have implemented this and this case is
working. Now my problem is

```
    I am trying to integrate the google sign-in. But while integrating the google sign-in, I am 
    getting authorized as anonymous user and I couldn't able proceed further. This is not the
   case I dont want.
   when ever user logged with google sign in option user must be able to sign in and could able to 
   generate the jwt token. How  can I solve my problem. I am using technology springboot and reactjs.
```

My security configuration code.

```
 public class Springsec extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .antMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/index.html","/error/**")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
  /*  http
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(auth)
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
```

}

Is Below one is the only way to solve my problem or is there any way to solve the problem

```
         google sign in must me authorized by reactjs then we have to send access token to the server 
         and generate the jwt token.

       If there is any other way pls help out. If possible send me sample code.
        If My guess is the only way to solve the problem, Then simply say yes.
```

Thank you.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written about this [here](https://blog.hcf.dev/article/2020-10-31-spring-boot-part-07).  Your configure method could look something like:

```java
    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {                                                                                                                                                                 
            http.antMatcher("/**")                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                .authorizeRequests(t -> t.anyRequest().authenticated())                                                                                                                                                                
                .formLogin(t -> t.loginPage("/login").permitAll())                                                                                                                                                                     
                .logout(t -> t.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))                                                                                                                                              
                              .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll());                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            try {                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                ClientRegistrationRepository repository =                                                                                                                                                                              
                    getApplicationContext().getBean(ClientRegistrationRepository.class);                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                if (repository != null) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
                    http.oauth2Login(t -> t.clientRegistrationRepository(repository)                                                                                                                                                   
                                           .userInfoEndpoint(u -> u.oidcUserService(oidcUserService))                                                                                                                                  
                                           .loginPage("/login").permitAll());                                                                                                                                                          
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            } catch (Exception exception) {                                                                                                                                                                                            
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            http.sessionManagement(t -> t.maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()));                                                                                                                                     
        }
```

and the OAuth2 configuration (in application.yaml):

```yaml
---
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            client-secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        provider:
          google:
            user-name-attribute: email
```

Comment: That's fine thanks for the reply,but how do we add jwt token for both form and oauth2 login.how do we validate the jwt token for osuth2

Comment: I am not aware of any Spring/Oauth2 provider that you could simply drop in.  If coexisting form login and Oauth2/OIDC isn't what you're looking for, then I suggest using a service like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) for SSO for your application.

Comment: [This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-resource-server) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: thank for you help your answer solved my problem